# Preloading images and adding class

Tags: javascript, preload

I am using the following code to preload my images:

```
function preload(sources)
{
  var images = [];
  for (i = 0, length = sources.length; i < length; ++i) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = sources[i];
  }
}
```

How can I add a class to the image object? I tried images[i].class = 'classname', but this doesn't do the trick. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `className` instead of `class`.

```
images[i].className  = "className";
```